# Организация удалённой отправки команд расширяемому клиенту

Tags: c#, сеть, проектирование, плагин

Суть вопроса вот в чём:

У меня есть толстый клиент. Я хочу управлять работой этого клиента с сервера. На сервере реализована панель управления с использованием паттерна "Команда", а у клиента имеется расширяемый набор функций для выполнения команд сервера. Смотрите код ниже.

Допустим, у клиента (получателя (Receiver) команд) есть функция "Run", которую будем вызывать с сервера:

```
class Receiver
{
    public int Register { get; private set; }

    public void Run(char operationCode, int operand)
    {
        switch (operationCode)
        {
            case '+': Register += operand; break;
            case '-': Register -= operand; break;
            case '*': Register *= operand; break;
            case '/': Register /= operand; break;
        }
    }
}
```

Код панели управления, реализованной на сервере:

```
//"Invoker" (Инициатор (вызыватель команд)) 
class Invoker
{
    private List<Command> commands = new List<Command>();
    private int current = 0;

    public void StoreCommand(Command command)
    {
        commands.Add(command);
    }

    public void ExecuteCommand()
    {
        commands[current++].Execute();
    }

    public void Undo(int levels)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < levels; i++)
            if (current > 0)
                commands[--current].UnExecute();
    }

    public void Redo(int levels)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < levels; i++)
            if (current < (commands.Count - 1))
                commands[current++].Execute();
    }
}

//"Command" (Какая-то (абстрактная) команда)
abstract class Command
{
    protected dynamic receiver;

    public Command(dynamic receiver)
    {
        this.receiver = receiver;
    }

    public abstract void Execute();
    public abstract void UnExecute();
}

//"ConcreteCommand" (Команда (сложение), которую сервер отправит клиенту)
class ConcreteCommand : Command
{
    int operand;

    public ConcreteCommand(Receiver receiver, int operand)
        : base(receiver)
    {
        this.operand = operand;
    }

    public override void Execute()
    {
        receiver.Run('+', operand);
    }

    public override void UnExecute()
    {
        receiver.Run('-', operand);
    }
}
```

### ----------

**Подскажите, пожалуйста, как лучше реализовать вызов метода (например, "Run") на стороне толстого клиента:**

---

*Сделать распределённое приложение, поместив в плагин (приложение расширяемое) следующий код:*

```
class Receiver : MarshalByRefObject
{
    public int Register { get; private set; }

    public void Run(char operationCode, int operand)
    {
        switch (operationCode)
        {
            case '+': Register += operand; break;
            case '-': Register -= operand; break;
            case '*': Register *= operand; break;
            case '/': Register /= operand; break;
        }
    }
}
```

, а на сервере просто делать вызов:

```
public override void Execute()
{
    receiver.Run('+', operand);
}
```

Но тогда, на клиенте, придётся динамически подключать этот плагин. А это означает, что придётся использовать медленную, ресурсоёмкую рефлексию. Если эту проблему решить, создав следующую разделяемую сборку:

```
class ReceiverRef : MarshalByRefObject
{
    public dynamic Ref { get; set; }
}
```

и однократно её подключив, делать на сервере вызовы следующего метода:

```
public override void Execute()
{
    ReceiverRef receiverRef = new ReceiverRef();
    receiverRef.Ref = receiver;
    receiverRef.Ref.Run('+', operand);
}
```

, то возникает необходимость подключать сервер к клиенту, когда клиент подключится к серверу и сообщит ему свой IP и номер порта. То есть они должны будут поменяться местами, потому что (насколько я знаю) в распределённых приложениях код выполняется на стороне сервера, а мне нужно, чтобы этот код (команду) выполнил мой толстый клиент. Но тогда постоянное ожидание клиентом подсоединения сервера будет сильно расходовать заряд батарейки устройства, на котором он установлен.

---

*Отправлять клиенту имя вызываемого метода в виде строки:*

```
class ConcreteCommand : Command
{
    int operand;

    public ConcreteCommand(Server receiver, int operand)
        : base(receiver)
    {
        this.operand = operand;
    }

    public override void Execute()
    {
        receiver.Send("Receiver.Run", '+', operand);
    }

    public override void UnExecute()
    {
        receiver.Send("Receiver.Run", '-', operand);
    }
}
```

, а в плагинах размещать необходимые методы (напоминаю, что клиент расширяемый). Но тогда снова возникает необходимость использования рефлексии (причём, многократного).

---

*Ваши идеи.*

---

Заранее вам благодарен.

Answer (score 0):

Способ передачи сообщений зависит от технологий, которые вы используете для обмена. Судя по MarshalByRefObject я предполагаю, что вы используете Remoting. В таком случае я бы предложил создать Data Transfer Object, который бы передавался между сервисами и содержал в себе информацию о команде и необходимые данные. Если у вас будут какие-то команды не вписывающиеся в стандартную модель, вы всегда сможете сделать наследника с дополнительными параметрами.

Для выполнения команд с возможностью добавления новых - посмотрите на шаблон Chain Of Responsibility. Receiver получает объект с командой и отправляет его по цепочке обработчиков. Обработчик, которому эта команда предназначена выполняет ее.
Для .net, если вы используете dependency injection, более удобно использовать модифицированную модель:

```
class CommandDescriptor {
    public char OpCode { get; set; }
    public int Operand { get; set; }
}

interface IProcessor {
    bool DoIt(command);
}

class AddCommandProcessor : IProcessor
{
    private readonly _registerHolder;

    // Важно, registerHolder должен быть зарегистрирован как singleton в вашем DI контроллере.
    public AddCommandProcessor(RegisterHolder registerHolder){
        _registerHolder = registerHolder;
    }

    public bool DoIt(command){
       if(command.OpCode == '+'){
         _registerHolder.Register += operand;
         return true;
       }
       return false;
    }
}

class Receiver : MarshalByRefObject {
    private readonly IProcessor[] _processors;
    // Ваши обработчики должны быть зарегистрированы в DI контроллере. Возможно сигнатура метода поменяется, в зависимости от того какой DI вы используете.
    public Receiver(IProcessor[] processors){
        _processors = processors
    }

    public Run(CommandDescriptor commandDescriptor){
        foreach(var processor in _processors){
            if(processor.DoIt(commandDescriptor)){
               return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Код писал без проверки, так что возможно потребуется поправить для компилируемости.